# Enterprise messaging and realiablitity

Tags: sql, rabbitmq, msmq, messaging, masstransit

all! I need an advise of experts here. I have a scenario where I have and .NET WebForms UI application performing poorly due to some business processes being triggered (depending on some user input). The current solution is MS SQL server based. I figured that some of those business processes can be off-loaded and processed asynchronously, so user don't have to wait on them and have better UI experience. Although, I need to be certain those business processes do get processed. As a solution, I am thinking of introduction of some sort of messaging system into the app, which will trigger those processes async. After much debates with business people one of the criteria for the messaging system is reliability - the messages should NEVER be lost. (Infrastructure and maintainability is the second one.) So here are my questions:

Which messaging system/platform you'd recommend for application internal messaging, which is cheap, reliable and does not get distributed transactions involved?

Right now I am considering use of SQL Service Broker - are there better alternatives? Is it reliable enough not to lose messages?

Should I build my own messaging system based of SQL Server?

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately there will be no definitive answer so your question will probably be closed.  However, you may want to consider a service bus.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953891/why-do-we-need-service-bus-frameworks-like-nservice-bus-masstransit-on-top-of-me/25957608#25957608 --- you'll need to evaluate a couple to see what works for you.

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ is a very popular open-source messaging framework that'll get done exactly what you're looking for. My team has done a lot of research on this same topic of yours and have chosen rabbitmq over other messaging frameworks like msmq and/or zeroMQ.

In the "asynchronous messaging" world, the term for the type of messaging you are looking for is "Durable messaging" and rabbitmq handles this well.

Durable messaging means that messages, when sent to a queue, are also persisted to disk. In addition to persistence, messages are NOT removed from the queue until the consumer of the message acknowledges that processing has completed successfully. This guarantees that you'll never lose a message!

Durable messaging is exactly what you're looking for, and everything you ever hoped for can be handled well by RabbitMQ.

Some people might mention the use of a "service bus". Beware of that term. Most people have varied beliefs on what that term means, and even vendors of "service buses" define the concept differently from one another. There are, however,  two service bus products out there that for your case you'll want to be aware of. They are MassTransit and NServiceBus. These two are code abstractions built on top of RabbitMQ and/or msmq. In a nutshell, they are used to facilitate coding of rabbitmq, and are NOT replacements for rabbitMQ or other queuing transports as other people might make it sound (think of them like a shell over rabbitmq or msmq). I would recommend using one of those products only if you are going to heavily use asynchronous messaging in your application, otherwise, you can use bare-bones RabbitMQ and you'll be fine.